# EPSG:3575 bounding box in projected coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, epsg

I've been trying to find out what the projected bounds are for EPSG:3575 but have not been able to find a definitive answer. Normally, I'd just use the values from EPSG.io but when I tried these in mapserver and geowebcache they both threw back error messages saying 'min x, miny, max x, max y not valid'. I've also tried the values from spatialreference.org and whilst these are valid, the cache gridset I created in GWC then did not work with several WMS services from other organisations. I have also found this site http://nsidc.org/data/atlas/epsg_3575.html, but this just gives the same info as the EPSG registry in effect. Ive tried converting the 4326 bbox to 3575 in a couple of programs (ogr and a web conversion site), but these just out with differing answers, neither of which look correct. any help would be gratfully received!

Answer (score 0):

From http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3575/

WGS84 Bounds: `-180.0000, 45.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000`

Projected Bounds: `0.0000, 0.0000, 849024.0785, 4815054.8210`